# Auto Reaction Roles / Discord.js Bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm having a slight issue getting my auto roles to work I have been trying to sort it via message.js and in the reactionrole.js but its still giving the same issue wondering if anyone can help would be appreciated as I have looked up about it via tutorials and apart from a few differences due to different text / details it does has not helped

Also I’m using Command handler V2 if that helps
Error

```html
(node:7712) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined at Object.execute (\commands\other\reactionrole.js:6:46) at module.exports (\events\guild\message.js:46:25) at Client.emit (events.js:376:20) at MessageCreateAction.handle
(node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14) at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22) at WebSocketShard.onMessage (\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10) at WebSocket.onMessage \node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:7712) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
(rejection id: 1) (node:7712) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

reactionrole.js

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: 'Sets Up Roles!',
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
        const channel = '860952043845058570'
        const vgmembers = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "VG Members");
        const vgamembers = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "VG-A Members");
        const vghmembers = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "VG-H Members");

        const vgmembersEmoji = `<:VG:860965732057219122>`;
        const vgamembersEmoji = `<:VGA:860964110434566154>`;
        const vghmembersEmoji = `<:VGH:860964110371913748>`;

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e42643')
        .setTitle('What Family Are You In')
        .setDescription('Select The Emjoi Of The Alliance You Are In \n\n'
        + `${vgmembersEmoji} If Your A VG Member\n`
        + `${vgamembersEmoji} If Your A VG-A Member\n`
        + `${vghmembersEmoji} If Your A VG-H Member`);

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(blueTeamEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === vgmembersEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(vgmembers);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === vgamembersEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(vgamembers);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === vghmembersEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(vghmembers);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === vgmembersEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(vgmembers);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === vgamembersEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(vgamembers);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === vghmembersEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(vghmembers);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

message.js

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { Console, time } = require('console');
const cooldowns = new Map();


module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;


    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;


    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find((a) => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
    if (!command) return message.channel.send("This Command Doesn't Exist!");

    if (command === "reactionrole"){
        client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, Discord, client);
      }

    if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }
  
    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    //If time_stamps has a key with the author's id then check the expiration time to send a message to a user.
    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

            return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
        }
    }
    //If the author's id is not in time_stamps then add them with the current time.
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    //Delete the user's id once the cooldown is over.
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `message.js` you have

```
if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
```

While in `reactionrole.js` you have

```
async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
```

This simply means that the value names are mismatched.

There are 3 ways to fix this.

1. Changing the order in your command file

Probably the best way to fix this.
Simply change the beginning of `reactionrole.js` to:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: 'Sets Up Roles!',
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord){
    //the rest of the code
```

2. Change your Command Handler output

This isn't advised, as you probably have other command files that already use the current format, but still possible.

Simply change the last line in `message.js` to

```
if(command) command.execute(message, args, Discord, client);
```

But that might mean having to change all the command files along with it.

3. Reformat the output and input

One of the best solutions is to use Objects.

In `message.js` change the last line to

```
if(command) command.execute({ client, message, args, Discord });
```

In command files, change the execute property to

```
async execute({ client, message, args, Discord }){
```

This will also allow you to only take specific properties in command files, and change the order in which you take them.

Examples:

- You can leave out the client, args and Discord properties if it's a simple response like so:

```
async execute({ message }){
```

- You can change the order without a penalty

```
async execute({ message, args, Discord, client }){
```

This will still work, even though the order changed.

The only thing you have to watch out for with this method is the capitalization.
If you were to type `discord` instead of `Discord` it wouldn't work.

Use any method you prefer, and a happy coding!

Comment: You are a life saver thanks man i took your 3. idea i appreciate the help i would upvote you but it would not let me because i need 15 reputation lol

Comment: @KazTeko No problem at all man, if you would consider accepting the answer as the correct one that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: done thanks again lol now to work on adding more to my RP bot xD

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild` seems to be undefined
Are you in direct (private) messages?

Comment: If you mean by doing the command in private message then no the command was typed in general chat